# How do I use a GPG key with Evolution mail?

Tags: gnupg, evolution

I've been using `gpg` in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 to generate and successfully use my keys. I don't see my keys in **Passwords and Keys**/**seahorse**. I've tried importing them via **.asc** and **.gpg**. It tells me they already exist.

Evolution isn't finding these keys either (because they aren't in passwords and keys???). I was using this [tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-enable-pgp-encryption-evolution) to find what I'm missing, but it's not specific enough.

I'm looking for pointers as to what I may be missing. Perhaps I'm using `gpg` incorrectly. Should I have been using `gpg2` this entire time? Do I need a plugin for **Evolution**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gpg2` is connected to **Passwords and Keys**. `gpg` is not.

I exported the private and public keys, per user, to a file with:
`gpg --export-secret-keys user > user-private.asc`

I had to import into `gpg2` using `sudo`:
`sudo gpg2 --import user-private.asc`
If `sudo` isn't used, a *general error* occurs.

I opened up **Passwords and Keys** and *then* was able to find those under GnuPG Keys. I opened each user and set the trust level to *Ultimate*.
Properties > Details > Actions > Override Owner Trust (choose **Ultimate**)

That allowed me to find those users in Evolution. I did not install any other plugins for Evolution.

Properties of email in Evolution > Security > Pretty Good Privacy (OpenPGP) > OpenPGP Key ID (choose user in drop-down selector)

Once those were done, I was able to encrypt and sign emails, send one to myself, and have it automatically decrypted via password prompts.